# Django-Guardian/Tastypie: Toggle object-level permissions from private to public

Tags: django, tastypie, django-guardian

I am using [django-guardian](http://django-guardian.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2/) to implement object-level permissions in my tastypie api and I would like to be able to toggle an instance of a resource's permissions between private, and public.

For example, I have an `Event` resource. When a `User` creates an `Event`, the `Event.creator` is set to the `User` instance. I use a a `post_save` signal on the `Event` to give object-level permissions the `User` who created it - making it private to the creator.

I want a `User` to be able toggle the permissions level for the `Event` to allow all users to be able to access it - aka change the Event from private to public (and back again).

What is the best way to handle this? I'd like to stick with guardian if possible, but am not married to it. Here are some snippets of code to help illustrate:

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    events = models.ManyToManyField('myapp.Event', through="myapp.EventMembership", null=True, blank=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    creator = models.ForeignKey('myapp.UserProfile', related_name="creator")
```

resources.py

```
class EventResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Event.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'events'
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = GuardianAuthorization(
            create_permission_code  = "myapp.add_event",
            view_permission_code    = "myapp.view_event",
            update_permission_code  = "myapp.change_event",
            delete_permission_code  = "myapp.delete_event"
        )
        always_return_data = True

    creator = fields.ForeignKey('myapp.UserProfile', 'creator', full=True)

    def hydrate(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle.obj.creator = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=bundle.request.user)
        return bundle
```

signals.py

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def allow_user_to_create_events(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not instance:
        return None

    if kwargs.get('created'):
        ApiKey.objects.create(user=instance)

    # give newly created user permissions to create events
    add_permission(instance, "myapp.add_event", Event)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Event)
def allow_user_to_edit_events(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance or not isinstance(instance, Event):
        return None

    # assign_perm is a guardian shortcut
    assign_perm("myapp.view_event", instance.creator.user, instance)
    assign_perm("myapp.edit_event", instance.creator.user, instance)
    assign_perm("myapp.delete_event", instance.creator.user, instance)
```

Thanks for your time and help!

**Note:** I am using the [guardian-authorization](https://gist.github.com/7wonders/6557760) in my tastypie resources. However, I think my question is more of a guardian question, and not so much about it's use with tastypie.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `guaridan-authorization` works. But in your authorization class you class you can always do a lookup and return `True` if the object has been set to public.